# Combine (rbind) data frames and create column with name of original data frames

Tags: r

I have several data frames that I want to combine by row. In the resulting single data frame, I want to create a new variable identifying which data set the observation came from.

```
# original data frames
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 3), y = c(2, 4))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(5, 7), y = c(6, 8))

# desired, combined data frame
df3  <- data.frame(x = c(1, 3, 5, 7), y = c(2, 4, 6, 8),
                   source = c("df1", "df1", "df2", "df2")
# x y source
# 1 2    df1
# 3 4    df1
# 5 6    df2
# 7 8    df2
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's not exactly what you asked for, but it's pretty close. Put your objects in a named list and use `do.call(rbind...)`

```
> do.call(rbind, list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2))
      x y
df1.1 1 2
df1.2 3 4
df2.1 5 6
df2.2 7 8
```

Notice that the row names now reflect the source `data.frame`s.

#### Update: Use `cbind` and `rbind`

Another option is to make a basic function like the following:

```
AppendMe <- function(dfNames) {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(dfNames, function(x) {
    cbind(get(x), source = x)
  }))
}
```

This function then takes a character vector of the `data.frame` names that you want to "stack", as follows:

```
> AppendMe(c("df1", "df2"))
  x y source
1 1 2    df1
2 3 4    df1
3 5 6    df2
4 7 8    df2
```

#### Update 2: Use `combine` from the "gdata" package

```
> library(gdata)
> combine(df1, df2)
  x y source
1 1 2    df1
2 3 4    df1
3 5 6    df2
4 7 8    df2
```

#### Update 3: Use `rbindlist` from "data.table"

Another approach that can be used now is to use `rbindlist` from "data.table" and its `idcol` argument. With that, the approach could be:

```
> rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "df\\d+")), idcol = TRUE)
   .id x y
1: df1 1 2
2: df1 3 4
3: df2 5 6
4: df2 7 8
```

#### Update 4: use `map_df` from "purrr"

Similar to `rbindlist`, you can also use `map_df` from "purrr" with `I` or `c` as the function to apply to each list element.

```
> mget(ls(pattern = "df\\d+")) %>% map_df(I, .id = "src")
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

    src     x     y
  (chr) (int) (int)
1   df1     1     2
2   df1     3     4
3   df2     5     6
4   df2     7     8
```

Comment: Yep, that was the exact same problem I was getting using the append function.  From there you can create a new variable = row.names and then parse everything after the period.  Thanks for your quick reply!

Answer (score 28):

Another approach using `dplyr`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,3), y = c(2,4))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(5,7), y = c(6,8))

df3 <- dplyr::bind_rows(list(df1=df1, df2=df2), .id = 'source')

df3
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

  source     x     y
   (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
1    df1     1     2
2    df1     3     4
3    df2     5     6
4    df2     7     8
```

Comment: For me, this gives a number for the dataframe (based on order called) instead of the actual dataframe name :o

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if such a function already exists, but this seems to do the trick:

```
bindAndSource <-  function(df1, df2) { 
  df1$source <- as.character(match.call())[[2]]
  df2$source <- as.character(match.call())[[3]]
  rbind(df1, df2)
}
```

### results:

```
bindAndSource(df1, df2)

1 1 2    df1
2 3 4    df1
3 5 6    df2
4 7 8    df2
```

---

Caveat:   This will not work in `*aply`-like calls

Comment: Oh, I like this method!  I'm not comfortable with using match.call yet, but the more I read these boards the more important it seems to be in creating functions!  Thanks dude!

Comment: @PaddyMaloney, use `match.call` cautiously.  ;)

Answer (score 6):

A blend of the other two answers:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3,y = 1:3)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 4:6,y = 4:6)

> foo <- function(...){
    args <- list(...)
    result <- do.call(rbind,args)
    result$source <- rep(as.character(match.call()[-1]),times = sapply(args,nrow))
    result
 }

> foo(df1,df2,df1)
  x y source
1 1 1    df1
2 2 2    df1
3 3 3    df1
4 4 4    df2
5 5 5    df2
6 6 6    df2
7 1 1    df1
8 2 2    df1
9 3 3    df1
```

If you want to avoid the `match.call` business, you can always limit yourself to naming the function arguments (i.e. `df1 = df1, df2 = df2`) and using `names(args)` to access the names.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround for this one is using ldply in the plyr package...

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,3), y = c(2,4))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(5,7), y = c(6,8))
list = list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)
df3 <- ldply(list)

df3
  .id x y
  df1 1 2
  df1 3 4
  df2 5 6
  df2 7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though there are already some great answers here, I just wanted to add the one I have been using.  It is base `R` so it might be be less limiting if you want to use it in a package, and it is a little faster than some of the other base `R` solutions.

```
dfs <- list(df1 = data.frame("x"=c(1,2), "y"=2),
            df2 = data.frame("x"=c(2,4), "y"=4),
            df3 = data.frame("x"=2, "y"=c(4,5,7)))

> microbenchmark(cbind(do.call(rbind,dfs), 
                       rep(names(dfs), vapply(dfs, nrow, numeric(1)))), times = 1001)
Unit: microseconds
     min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
 393.541 409.083 454.9913 433.422 453.657 6157.649  1001
```

The first part, `do.call(rbind, dfs)` binds the rows of data frames into a single data frame.  The `vapply(dfs, nrow, numeric(1))` finds how many rows each data frame has which is passed to `rep` in `rep(names(dfs), vapply(dfs, nrow, numeric(1)))` to repeat the name of the data frame once for each row of the data frame.  `cbind` puts them all together.

This is similar to a previously posted solution, but about 2x faster.

```
> microbenchmark(do.call(rbind, 
                         lapply(names(dfs), function(x) cbind(dfs[[x]], source = x))), 
                 times = 1001)
Unit: microseconds
      min      lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
  844.558 870.071 1034.182 896.464 1210.533 8867.858  1001
```

I am not 100% certain, but I believe the speed up is due to making a single call to `cbind` rather than one per data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `Map`. First, I create a named list of dataframes. Then, I can `cbind` the names to each dataframe. Then, use `unname` to remove the row names. Finally, `rbind` all the dataframes together.

```
# original data frames
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 3), y = c(2, 4))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(5, 7), y = c(6, 8))

df.list <- Hmisc::llist(df1, df2)

do.call(rbind, unname(Map(cbind, source = names(df.list), df.list)))
```

**Output**

```
  source x y
1    df1 1 2
2    df1 3 4
3    df2 5 6
4    df2 7 8
```