# r data.frame with a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data.frame(read in from jsonlite::fromJSON) which contains some list of data.frame, for example:

```
# > str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ id           : int  1 2
# $ name         : chr  "Julie" "Justin" 
# $ score        :List of 2
# ..$ : NULL
# ..$ :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ rid               : int  1 2 3 4 5
# .. ..$ math              : int  5 17 19 12 16
```

I want to convert the data into the following form:

```
# id   name score.rid score.math
#  1  Julie       NA        NA
#  2 Justin       1         5
#  2 Justin       2         17
#  2 Justin       3         19
#  2 Justin       4         12
#  2 Justin       5         16
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine (rbind) data frames and create column with name of original data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162197/combine-rbind-data-frames-and-create-column-with-name-of-original-data-frames)

Comment: Could you please show the `dput` of the example. May be with `tidyverse` `dat %>% mutate(score =  map(score, ~if(is.null(.x)) tibble(rid = rep(NA, 5),  math = rep(NA, 5)) else as_tibble(.x)))   %>% unnest` could work.  It is not clear why the row for 'Julie' should be the same

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That post is about to rbind two data.frames, but my question is about to convert a data.frame which contains a list

Comment: @akrun that was my fault, I will update the question

Comment: Also, is it possible to have more than 2 nested datasets with different number of rows and in that case if there is a `NULL` dataset what will be the number of rows for that

Comment: with the updated post, you can remove the `rep` and instead use `tibble(rid = NA, math = NA)` i.e. `dat %>% mutate(score =  map(score, ~if(is.null(.x)) tibble(rid = NA, math = NA) else as_tibble(.x)))   %>% unnest`

Comment: Or to make it more dynamic `dat %>% mutate(score =  map(score, ~ if(is.null(.x)) tibble(NA) else as_tibble(.x))) %>% unnest %>% select(-`NA`)`  The `NA` within select is within backquotes

Comment: @akrun The function `map`belongs to which package?

Comment: @velvetrock  It belong to `purrr`

Answer (score 0):

For `score` values that are `NULL`, change it to `NA` using `map` from `purrr`, then convert to `tibble` and `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
   mutate(score = map(score, ~ if(is.null(.x)) tibble(NA) else as_tibble(.x))) %>% 
   unnest %>%
   select(-`NA`)
#  id   name rid math
#1  1  Julie  NA   NA
#2  2 Justin   1    5
#3  2 Justin   2   17
#4  2 Justin   3   19
#5  2 Justin   4   12
#6  2 Justin   5   16
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:2, name = c("Julie", "Justin"),
      score = I(list(NULL, data.frame(rid = 1:5, 
      math = c(5, 17, 19, 12, 16)))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```