# ggplot: use same shape/color across plots with different category combinations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a number of plots, in which different combinations of categories appear. So for example, plot 1 has categories A,B,D plot 2 has A, C,D, and plot 3 has A, B, C, D. How can I tell ggplot to use the same shape and color for the same categories every plot?

my setup is basically like this:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(sample(4), sample(4), c("A", "A", "B", "D")))
df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(sample(4), sample(4), c("B", "C", "C", "D")))
df3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(sample(4), sample(4), c("A","B", "C", "D")))

df.lst <- list(df1, df2, df3)

plt.lst <- list()

for(df in df.lst){

     plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x=V1, y=V2, color=V3, shape=V3)) +
         geom_point()

     plt.lst[[length(plt.lst)+1]] <- plt
}

grid.arrange(grobs=plt.lst)
```

which gives me the same categories with different shapes/colors :(

[image]

Comment: [Create a single dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162197/combine-rbind-data-frames-and-create-column-with-name-of-original-data-frames) from `df.lst` and use `facet_grid` / `facet_wrap`, if that is an option for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overview

Using @markus's suggestion, binding all of your data frames into one `df` prior to creating your 3x1 plot (courtesy of [`facet_wrap()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html)) will allow you to see the same shape/color across plots with different category combinations.

[image: SS of facet wrap]

## Code

```
# load necessary package -------
library(tidyverse)

# collapse individual data frames into one --------
# so that your data is tidy
df <-
  list(df1 = data.frame(cbind(sample(4), sample(4), c("A", "A", "B", "D")))
       , df2 = data.frame(cbind(sample(4), sample(4), c("B", "C", "C", "D")))
       , df3 = data.frame(cbind(sample(4), sample(4), c("A","B", "C", "D")))) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "origin")

# create a 3x1 plot -------
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X1, y = X2, color = X3, shape = X3)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(origin), nrow = 3, ncol = 1)

# end of script #
```