# Binding lists of data frames while preserving index

Tags: r, dplyr

There are many posts on converting list of data frames to single data frame ([ex. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851327/convert-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame)). However, I need to do that while preserving information from which list 
resulting rows are, i.e. I need to preserve an index of original list. If the list is unnamed, I need just an index number, while if the list is named I need to save the name of original list element. How can I do that?

With the data like below:

```
foo <- list(data.frame(x=c('a', 'b', 'c'),y = c(1,2,3)), 
            data.frame(x=c('d', 'e', 'f'),y = c(4,5,6)))
```

I need an output like this:

```
  index x y
1     1 a 1
2     1 b 2
3     1 c 3
4     2 d 4
5     2 e 5
6     2 f 6
```

while with named elements of a list:

```
foo <- list(df1 = data.frame(x=c('a', 'b', 'c'),y = c(1,2,3)), 
            df2 = data.frame(x=c('d', 'e', 'f'),y = c(4,5,6)))
```

the output would be:

```
  index x y
1   df1 a 1
2   df1 b 2
3   df1 c 3
4   df2 d 4
5   df2 e 5
6   df2 f 6
```

Comment: Seems related: [Combine (rbind) data frames and create column with name of original data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162197/combine-rbind-data-frames-and-create-column-with-name-of-original-data-frames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `imap` to get the index

```
library(purrr)
imap_dfr(foo, ~ .x %>% 
              mutate(index = .y))
```

Or with `map`

```
map_dfr(foo, .f = cbind, .id = 'index')
#  index x y
#1     1 a 1
#2     1 b 2
#3     1 c 3
#4     2 d 4
#5     2 e 5
#6     2 f 6
```

---

Or use `Map` from `base R`, where we loop through the elements of 'foo' and a corresponding sequence of 'foo', `cbind` to create a new column and then `rbind` the `list` elements

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, index = seq_along(foo), foo))
#  index x y
#1     1 a 1
#2     1 b 2
#3     1 c 3
#4     2 d 4
#5     2 e 5
#6     2 f 6
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, thanks! btw. you've got a typo in the first sentence - shouldn't be `imap`?

Comment: @jakes Thanks.  It is `imap_dfr` does row bind, `imap_dfc` - column bind

Answer (score 1):

You could name the list if it is unnamed and then loop over them using `lapply` to create list of dataframes and `rbind` them together as one dataframe.

```
names(foo) <- if (is.null(names(foo))) seq_len(length(foo)) else names(foo)

do.call("rbind", lapply(names(foo), function(x) cbind(index = x, foo[[x]])))


#  index x y
#1     1 a 1
#2     1 b 2
#3     1 c 3
#4     2 d 4
#5     2 e 5
#6     2 f 6
```

For named list

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(names(foo), function(x) cbind(index = x, foo[[x]])))

#  index x y
#1   df1 a 1
#2   df1 b 2
#3   df1 c 3
#4   df2 d 4
#5   df2 e 5
#6   df2 f 6
```