# How to add an id colum to a list of data.frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, lapply

I'm `rbind`ing a list (`k`) of data.frames into a single data.frame (`current_output`).

But I'm wondering how to add an `id` column to my resultant data.frame so that I get my `desred_output` in BASE R?

```
k = list(A = data.frame(d = 1, n = 2), B = data.frame(d = 1:2, n = 2:3))

current_output = do.call(rbind, k)
#    d n
#A   1 2
#B.1 1 2
#B.2 2 3

desired_ouput1 = data.frame(id = c(1,2,2), d = c(1,1:2), n = c(2,2:3))
#  id d n
#1  1 1 2
#2  2 1 2
#3  2 2 3

desired_ouput2 = data.frame(id = c(A,B,B), d = c(1,1:2), n = c(2,2:3))
#  id d n
#1  A 1 2
#2  B 1 2
#3  B 2 3
```

Comment: @Henrik, would that be possible to provide a BASE R solution? much appreciated.

Comment: See [Combine (rbind) data frames and create column with name of original data frames)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162197/combine-rbind-data-frames-and-create-column-with-name-of-original-data-frames) for several `base` alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to have base R solution, the code below might help you

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  c(Map(cbind, id = names(k), k),
    make.row.names = FALSE
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  id d n
1  A 1 2
2  B 1 2
3  B 2 3
```

---

Or you can do

```
cbind(
  id = rep(
    names(k),
    sapply(k, nrow)
  ),
  do.call(rbind, k)
)
```

which gives

```
    id d n
A    A 1 2
B.1  B 1 2
B.2  B 2 3
```